# Issue With Passing Data Programmatically Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, programmatically-created

I am having trouble passing data from one UICollectionViewController to another UICollectionViewController programmatically.

Currently my setup is as follows:

1. The UICollectionViewController that is passing the data (`RestaurantController`)

   1a. A UICollectionViewCell (`RestaurantCell`)

   - this UICollectionViewCell has a nested UICollectionViewController within it with another custom UICollectionViewCell (`RestaurantCollectionViewCell`)
2. The UICollectionViewController that is receiving the data (`MenuController`)

   2a. A UICollectionViewCell (`MenuCell`)

Inside of my `RestaurantCell` I am loading data from JSON and appending it a new array as called restaurants: `var restaurants = [RestaurantModel]()`. But when I try to load the restaurant name or any of the restaurant objects in my `MenuController` using `var restaurant: RestaurantModel?`, I get nil values. I have a feeling either my setup is incorrect or I'm making a stupid mistake somewhere. Perhaps both. I have pasted my code below for each class.

**Where the values are returning nil inside of MenuController:**

`print("Restaurant Name:", restaurant?.name)`

`print("Restaurant Id:", restaurant?.id)`

**Is the custom delegation causing the issue?**

You help and advice is greatly appreciated!

Inside of my `RestaurantController`:

```
 import UIKit
 import FBSDKLoginKit

 class RestaurantController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, SWRevealViewControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, RestaurantDelegate {

var restaurantCell: RestaurantCell?

private let restaurantCellId = "restaurantCellId"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.qpizzaWhite()
    collectionView?.register(RestaurantCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: restaurantCellId)


    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_menu_24dp").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

}

// FIXME: issue with this...navigationcontroller is presenting, not pushing ontop of stack view
func didTapRestaurantCell(cell: RestaurantCell) {
    print("Did Tap Restaurant Cell - Restaurant Controller")

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let controller = MenuController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: restaurantCellId, for: indexPath) as! RestaurantCell
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}
}
```

Inside of my `RestaurantCell`:

```
protocol RestaurantDelegate {
    func didTapRestaurantCell(cell: RestaurantCell)
}


class RestaurantCell: BaseCell, UISearchBarDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var delegate: RestaurantDelegate?
var restaurants = [RestaurantModel]()
var filteredRestaurants = [RestaurantModel]()

private let restaurantCollectionViewCell = "restaurantCollectionViewCell"
private let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

lazy var searchBar: UISearchBar = {
    let sb = UISearchBar()
    sb.placeholder = "Search Restaurant"
    sb.barTintColor = .white
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.qpizzaWhite()
    sb.delegate = self
    return sb
}()

lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = .white
    return cv
}()

override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()
    collectionView.register(RestaurantCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: restaurantCollectionViewCell)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    backgroundColor = UIColor.qpizzaRed()

    addSubview(searchBar)
    addSubview(collectionView)

    _ = searchBar.anchor(topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 4, leftConstant: 4, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 4, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 50)

    _ = collectionView.anchor(searchBar.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

     loadRestaurants()

}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    print(searchText)

    filteredRestaurants = self.restaurants.filter({ (restaruant: RestaurantModel) -> Bool in

        return restaruant.name?.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil
    })

    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}

// MARK - Helper Methods
func loadRestaurants() {

    showActivityIndicator()

    APIManager.shared.getRestaurants { (json) in
        if json != .null {
            //                print("Restaurant JSON:", json)
            self.restaurants = []

            if let restaurantList = json["restaurants"].array {
                for item in restaurantList {
                    let restaurant = RestaurantModel(json: item)
                    self.restaurants.append(restaurant)
                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                self.hideActivityIndicator()
            }
        } else {
            print("Error loading JSON into Restaurant ViewController")
        }
    }
}

func loadImage(imageView: UIImageView, urlString: String) {

    let imageUrl: URL = URL(string: urlString)!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageUrl) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error loading image for Restaurant Controller:", error.localizedDescription)
        }
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        })
        }.resume()
}

func showActivityIndicator() {
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0)
    activityIndicator.center = center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
    activityIndicator.color = UIColor.qpizzaGold()

    addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

func hideActivityIndicator() {
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}

//MARK: CollectionView Delegate & DataSource Methods
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: restaurantCollectionViewCell, for: indexPath) as! RestaurantCollectionViewCell
    let restaurant: RestaurantModel

    if searchBar.text != "" {
        restaurant = filteredRestaurants[indexPath.item]
    } else {
        restaurant = restaurants[indexPath.item]
    }

    cell.restaurantNameLabel.text = restaurant.name
    cell.restaurantAddressLabel.text = restaurant.address

    if let logoName = restaurant.logo {
        let url = "\(logoName)"
        loadImage(imageView: cell.restaurantLogoImageView, urlString: url)
    }

    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchBar.text != "" {
        return self.filteredRestaurants.count
    }

    return self.restaurants.count
}

//FIXME: Restaurant Name Navigation Title is still not be passed from RestaurantCell to MenuController
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Did Select Item - Restaurant Cell")

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let controller = MenuController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    controller.restaurant = self.restaurants[indexPath.item]

    print("Controller", controller.restaurant) // Optional(QpizzaDelivery.RestaurantModel)
    print("Restaurant:", self.restaurants) // [QpizzaDelivery.RestaurantModel, QpizzaDelivery.RestaurantModel, QpizzaDelivery.RestaurantModel]
    print("IndexPath:", self.restaurants[indexPath.item]) // QpizzaDelivery.RestaurantModel

    delegate?.didTapRestaurantCell(cell: self)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: frame.width, height: 200)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.5
}

}
```

Inside of my `MenuController`:

```
import UIKit

class MenuController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {

private let menuCellId = "menuCellId"

var restaurant: RestaurantModel?
var menuItems = [MenuItemsModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.qpizzaWhite()
    collectionView?.register(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: menuCellId)
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true

    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu2-black-32").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    print("Restaurant Name:", restaurant?.name) // returns nil
    if let restaurantName = restaurant?.name {
        self.navigationItem.title = restaurantName
    }

    loadMenuItems()

}

func loadMenuItems() {
    print("Restaurant Id:", restaurant?.id) // returns nil
    if let restaurantId = restaurant?.id {
        print("RestaurantId:", restaurantId)
    }
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: menuCellId, for: indexPath) as! MenuCell
    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let controller = MenuDetailsController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 120)
}

}
```

Inside of my `MenuCell`:

```
import UIKit

class MenuCell: BaseCell {

let restaurantLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Restaurant King"
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    label.textColor = .black
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

let mealImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "button_chicken").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    return iv
}()

let mealDetailsLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Grass fed grass, American cheese, and friez"
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    label.textColor = UIColor.qpizzaBlack()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

let mealPriceLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "$12.00"
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    label.textColor = UIColor.qpizzaBlack()
    return label
}()

let sepereatorView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    return view
}()


override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()

    backgroundColor = UIColor.qpizzaWhite()

    addSubview(restaurantLabel)
    addSubview(mealImageView)
    addSubview(mealDetailsLabel)
    addSubview(mealPriceLabel)
    addSubview(sepereatorView)

    _ = mealImageView.anchor(topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 14, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 12, widthConstant: 60, heightConstant: 60)
    _ = restaurantLabel.anchor(topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: mealImageView.leftAnchor, topConstant: 14, leftConstant: 12, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 10, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 20)
    _ = mealDetailsLabel.anchor(restaurantLabel.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: mealImageView.leftAnchor, topConstant: 12, leftConstant: 12, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 10, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 30)
    _ = mealPriceLabel.anchor(mealDetailsLabel.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 10, leftConstant: 12, bottomConstant: 10, rightConstant: 10, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 20)
    _ = sepereatorView.anchor(nil, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 20, bottomConstant: 4, rightConstant: 20, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 1)


}
}
```

Comment: Been awhile since I messed w/CollectionView, but why is `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` inside the cell & not the controller? You're also apparently creating 2 different `MenuController` instances, one in the cell's `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method, and then another one in the `RestaurantDelegate` `didTapRestaurantCell` method which doesn't set the `restaurant` property. In the first one you set the restaurant, but that controller instance just hangs around for a bit & isn't used - it's not the one pushed by the nav controller.

Comment: `didSelectItemAtIndexPath' is inside of `RestaurantCell` because I have a nested UICollectionViewController inside of `RestaurantCell`. You are correct in stating that I am creating two different `MenuController`. I am not sure how to reference `MenuController` inside of `RestaurantCell` though without creating a new instance...do you have any tips?

Comment: I need the 1st instance of `MenuController` in `RestaurantController` to push the nav controller on the stack and 2nd instance of `MenuController` in `RestaurantCell` to get the reference of `restaurant` (which references my Restaurant Model) on my `MenuController`

Comment: @a2b123 Why are you passing cell back to controller class? Why not just pass the data back and segue that data? Your protocol should hold data of type restaurants(Which is your model array), when you tap a cell you can get data for that cell , and give to protocol, it will delegate it back to controller class , and then your segue will take it to another class.

Comment: @TusharSharma, I dont have any segues. Everything is being done programmatically. Is it possible for you to provide some example code?

Comment: @a2b123 I mean to say the delegation part, where you are passing cell back, just pass tapped cell data back, and when call goes back to controller class, you can send data to second class.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick look, declaring a variable of the correct type is the start.  But you actually have to do an assignment (=) to move data or the class reference from once class to the next.

```
func didTapRestaurantCell(cell: RestaurantCell) {
  print("Did Tap Restaurant Cell - Restaurant Controller")

  let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
  let controller = MenuController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
  navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

  // you need to set the restaurant attribute of your new 
  // controller
  let indexPath = indexPath(for: cell)
  controller.restaurant = self.restaurants[indexPath.item]
}
```

Comment: how do i get access to `restaurants` though in my `RestaurantController`. I've declared that variable within my `RestaurantCell`. Also how would I get access to `indexPath.item` in my `RestaurantController`? @ahalls. ive tried doing that method several times, but i'm just not sure how to access those pieces

Comment: This isn't enough  you have to map the Cell to the element in the `restaurants` array.

Comment: I don't see how you populate the cell in the first place?

Comment: `func indexPath(for: UICollectionViewCell)
Returns the index path of the specified cell.`

Comment: Sorry I'm not following your over all code ... but what is missing is the actual assignment (=) of the attribute value of your MenuController after create it. 

Declaring an attribute of the correct type is the necessary first step, making the assignment to the actual instance of the class is the next

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who commented and assisted me in figuring this out. I was able to solve my issue by changing my protocol and passing the controller as a parameter.

In `RestaurantCell`:

```
protocol RestaurantDelegate {
    func didTapRestaurantCell(cell: RestaurantCell, withMenuController: MenuController)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Did Select Item - Restaurant Cell")

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let controller = MenuController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    controller.restaurant = self.restaurants[indexPath.item]
    delegate?.didTapRestaurantCell(cell: self, withMenuController: controller)
}
```

In `RestaurantController`:

```
func didTapRestaurantCell(cell: RestaurantCell, withMenuController controller: MenuController) {
    print("Did Tap Restaurant Cell - Restaurant Controller")
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```